# How to place light guide film cuts as part of layer PCB

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, led-strip, pcb-layers, keypad

How can I go about doing something like this in fusion/ eagle?

https://www.pannam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Implementing-LGF.pdf

and

https://www.snaptron.com/2021/03/how-to-place-metal-dome-arrays-on-your-circuit-board/

Do I need to create a new layer? Its beyond what I have done yet.

From my understanding, I want to place LGF over each of my membrane keys. I think I need to place a liner, then the metal dome keys, then the venting layer, then the LGF, then the Top layer.
I want to do all of this on a flex pcb.

Anyone have experience in this? How do I specify the liner, LGF, venting layer, etc. Is there another software better for this type of modification. Id rather stay in fusion electronics if possible.

3m tape will attach the flex pcb to the back of another board, which has the side firing leds mounted. I made a hole around each led firing towards the button. They are controlled by an IC that is constant current, where I can adjust the brightness on the MC.

On top of the whole thing we will build a molded button pad that goes over each button with a clear section of whatever we want for each button. Maybe a ring or a letter or triangle, etc.